# Testing a Scala Aplication with ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have been going through documentations on ScalaTest but able to figure out what type of approach i should take for testing the app.

Code is divided amoung controller and service.
eg. Controller Code example

```
@Singleton
class Controller1 @Inject()(service1: ServiceClass1, authAction : AuthAction)
    extends InjectedController {
//returns a list[]
  def getSomeValue() = authAction {
    val res = service1.getValue1()
    val json = Json.toJson(res)
    Ok(json)
  }
}
```

Service Code Example -:

```
def getValue1() = {
    implicit val graph = db.g

    val infos = graph.V.hasLabel[someModel].toList()
    infos.map(vertex => {
      val someModel = vertex.toCC[someModel]
      val item = info(someId =
                              someModel.someId.getOrElse("").toString,
                            category = SomeModel.category,
                            description = someModel.description)
      item
    })
  }
```

I am very new to Testing and Scala both, I also understand the code but not able to understand where to begin. 
This is just a sample code which is very similar.

Comment: What is this? Play framework? Play have their own ScalaTest spec. Also what is the behavior you are trying to test? It is a very different story between unit tests, feature tests and integration tests. This question needs more clarity, too broad as it sits.

Comment: Yes this is a play framework, i want to do unit test for each def in the class, but most of the def are dependent on other service methods, eg -> in controller class -> res = service1.getValue1().  Also def getSomeValue() is dependent on authAuth.
How do i take care of that?
i am ery new to scala as well as testing, so i am not sure whether you got my question, if any queries, please clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you're looking for is a way to mock `service1.getValue1()` in your `Controller1`.

Scalatest supports a couple different ways to do this: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects

In your case, to test `def getSomeValue()`; you'd need to define a mock and set the right expectations so that when called from the test, the mock returns the expected responses.

If you'd like to use scala mock, you'd need to add it as a dependency in your sbt build config. You can do that by adding this dependency to your tests:

```
  "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock" % "4.4.0" % Test
```

And then, your test could be something like this:

```scala
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class Controller1Spec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {
  "Controller1" should "respond with a valid response" in {
    val mockService = mock[ServiceClass1]
    (mockService.getValue1 _).when().returning("Some Response").once()

    val mockAuthAction = mock[AuthAction] //assuming you've got an action called AuthAction
    //you'd need to mock this one too, in order for it to work
    (mockAuthAction.invokeBlock _) expects(_) onCall((r,b) => b(r))

    new Controller1(mockService, mockAuthAction) shouldBe Ok("Some Response")
  }
}
```

There's a number of posts on mocking for Scala which you should be able to find, like this one here: https://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/